# Changing multiple datatable entries with a single bound textbox

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bindingsource, datatable, datagridview, and a textbox (bound to a column).

They are appropriately bound so that a change to a textbox will change the appropriate entry for the selected row in appropriate column within the datatable/datagridview.

This works beautifully, but when I select more than one row in the datagridview, my edit in the textbox only applies to the last selected row.

How to I apply edits to the appropriate column for all selected rows?

```
//Declaring
DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();
BindingSource bsMain = new BindingSource();

private void Filling()
{
   // ... fill dtMain ...
   bsMain.DataSource = dtMain;
   dgvMain.DataSource = bsMain;

   //Binding txtData to the "Data" column that is populated into dtMain.
   txtData.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", bsMain, "Data", true));
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code

Comment: @viveknuna it's pretty basic code, unfortunately. Added above.